# Vista Ubuntu Dual Boot Problem

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I downloaded Ubuntu (I think version 14 point something, but not sure how to check the version), afterward I checked my download directory and I have an application file and an ISO file. I burned a DVD with the ISO file and loaded Ubuntu from the DVD. During the installation I gave Ubuntu much more space on the drive than required because I didn't know how much to give it- I think I gave it 88GB. I was asked to click on something that would allow my computer to boot from disk and agreed so that I wouldn't have to worry with going into the BIOS. Afterward, I was able to boot Ubuntu and was happy until I discovered that Windows Vista needed repair in order to boot. I did have the screen that asked which operating system to use. I repaired the Windows boot by going to a microsoft site that explained options to type into the command line. After repairing Windows boot, Ubuntu won't boot. Please advise!

Comment: It's simple, Vista's bootloader doesn't boot Ubutnu, Ubuntu's bootloader does boot Vista. In other words, by recovering Vista's bootloader, you've made Ubuntu unbootable. To undo the damage, try to [repair grub](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that you had ubuntu installed and not pressed the ''try ubuntu'' with the disk as an image,right?
You could try re-installing ubuntu or, as I suggest you, replace Windows Vista with Windows 7 and move all the files you want to keep in the ubuntu partition, also now that I said that are you sure you created a partition first and not installed ubuntu on the same drive as Vista?

Comment: Windows is booting now. Why should @user3523983 replace it with Windows 7 and move files between partitions?